# How to prevent the content in mobile devices to stop overflowing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I am experiencing a weird issue with my making my website responsive.

I basically have this output of my website on mobile devices:

[image]

Even though my `body` is set to `overflow-x: hidden;`, there is still white space and I can scroll on the x axis. I do not know why this is happening even though I have set it to hidden.

One thing, however, that might be making this happen is this right here:

[image]

When I scroll to the end of the website and then scroll on the x-axis to the farthest right, I see these things. Both the banner and the `New` icon should appear at the start of my website but somehow I see them at the bottom.

Basically, I am looking for this output:

[image]

I even added `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` but I don't know why my website is not the same width as the device. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post css + html code?

Comment: make sure your next child element after body also has overflow hidden

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your html element also has overflow-x: hidden:

```css
html, body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```